# Is it possible to clear a specific app's notification from notification centre after 30 sec in iOS?

Tags: push-notification, swift4, notificationcenter

I am receiving  push notifications from server in every 15 minutes. If my app is in background or inactive state the notification is placed at notification centre as expected.
I need to clear the notification after 30 sec to avoid calling UIApplication delegate method is given below.

func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], 
   fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)